# How to force Maven to download all test plugins without running any test?

Tags: maven

## Problem:

We have an internal company Artifactory server for our Maven dependencies. We have a dedicated Maven  project with test cases and some of our internal libraries are used in this project. The Artifactory server is reachable from our CI so all the artifacts can be pulled during build process.

Our goal is to run the tests from that project in Docker container in a private cluster without access to internal repository - for practical purposes, we can assume that `mvn test` is invoked offline.

That means that as part of the build process, I want to package test project and all required dependencies into an Docker image so that I can run tests safely in offline environment without need to pull anything.

## My approach:

The current approach is to make sure that .m2 repo is part of the image and then invoke this command in Dockerfile:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

The command downloads many Maven plugins (so that they are in .m2/repository now).

Then in the test environment I invoke:

```
mvn test -o
```

However, the latter command produces error when running the container:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
(...)
[INFO]
[INFO] Building test-project 1.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ test-project ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /workspace/test-project/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ test-project ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ test-project ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ test-project ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ test-project ---
[WARNING] Missing POM for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit-platform:jar:2.22.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.908 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-12T07:43:40Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project test-project: Unable to generate classpath: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.MultipleArtifactsNotFoundException: Missing:
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit-platform:jar:2.22.2
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR]       mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.surefire -DartifactId=surefire-junit-platform -Dversion=2.22.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR]       mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.surefire -DartifactId=surefire-junit-platform -Dversion=2.22.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Path to dependency:
[ERROR]     1) dummy:dummy:jar:1.0
[ERROR]     2) org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit-platform:jar:2.22.2
[ERROR]
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1 required artifact is missing.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] for artifact:
[ERROR]   dummy:dummy:jar:1.0
[ERROR]
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR]   central (http://company-repo.org/artifactory/plugins-release, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR]   snapshots (http://company-repo.org.org/artifactory/plugins-snapshot, releases=true, snapshots=true)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I'm not sure if dummy.jar is part of my project setup but I think that error can be ignored.

It seems to me that `org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit-platform` plugin is not available. And when I looked at the build command output I confirmed that it succeeds without ever invoking this plugin (and so without ever pulling it to local repository):

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests

(...)
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ test-project ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ test-project ---
(...)
```

So the problem is: how do I prepare Maven to run tests in "offline" mode without actually running the tests?

1. I could run all the tests in the build command, but it would waste a lot of time and results are useless anyway (tests only produce meaningful results in isolated cluster)
2. I tried to use option `-Dtest` with "match-nothing" pattern but the plugin wasn't pulled (apparently it activates only if there are some tests to run)
3. I tried `mvn dependency:go-offline` which pulled in hundreds of dependencies but not those for test
4. I could add explicit dependency to all test plugins in my pom.xml but it would become maintenance burden (difficult version upgrade, possibly multiple plugins required etc.)

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want to give your Docker container access to your Artifactory?

Comment: @JFMeier company's policy, probably some security requirement

Comment: I always would try to change the company policy first, and only if this turns out to be impossible, try to build around it. Company policies are not laws.

Comment: In contrast with title I make dummy/empty test which I run during image creation and it download all dependencies so i can run tests offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look to https://github.com/qaware/go-offline-maven-plugin, maybe it can help. It has been developed to fix some issues of the maven-dependency-plugin.

Comment: Thanks. One paragraph from the docs sort of answered my question: dynamic dependencies are loaded on runtime. Apparently I need to specify plugins versions anyway because there is no way to make it automatic. I guess I will go with this approach.